# Flex odometer component

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, components, ilog-elixir

Is there such a thing as a ready to go (as in SWC lib) Odometer-like component for Flex 4?
Google doesn't show anything valueable, TourDeFlex says ILog elixir has something but it doesn't show in the examples.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a gauge using ILog Elixir. Here is an example of what you can do with this: http://visunetdemos.demos.ibm.com/webdemos/gauges/gauges.html

And you can find a small tutorial on how to create a gauge using Flex 4 and ILog Elixir here: [ILOG Elixir Gauges using Flex 4 (aka Gumbo) FXG](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/elixir/entry/ilogelixirgaugesusingflex4akagumbofxg?lang=en)